# Gameobject.transform returning zero (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a game object (container) with an array of game objects (contents). All this objects are in a scene.

At container's Start function I try to retrieve positions of the contents but some of them are returning (0,0,0).

Someone knows what's happening?

Comment: Well, without further information I'd say they are at  0,0,0.

Comment: Post your code that fills the array of gameobjects. Are you sure some of these are not positioned to 0,0,0?

Comment: I add the objects with drag and drop from the scene to an script component. There are not content positioned at 0,0,0

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at the local positions? If an object has a parent, its coordinates start from the parent's position.

Comment: I'm getting positions using GetComponent<RectTransform>().positions.

Some objects return the position correctly and others doesn't.

Comment: RectTransform? Are these GUI elements? If not, you should be using at transform.position instead. As noted by Gunnar, you haven't provided us with enough information to diagnose your problem yet. A code snippet, and a screenshot of your scene hierarchy (with properties of an example object returning the wrong position) may be helpful.